# Hover over content div to reveal read more link

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and trying to learn and also implement. What I would like to do is have a content div that maybe holds an image, header and content. When this div is hovered over the div is overlayed with a transparent color and a read more link is also displayed.

Can anyone give me some advice on how this would be achieved or if there are any good tutorials online that can teach me this technique?

Comment: Do you have any mock-up images? What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is where Im at with this so far, Im having problems actually centering the read more link dead center however? http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/DmyGt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently made [a plugin that includes what you're after](http://thefinishedbox.com/freebies/plugins/jquery-zoom-plugin/).

You'll want to set the zoom to 0, let me know if you use it and need any help setting it up: [Here's a link to the demo](http://thefinishedbox.com/files/freebies/hoverzoom/index.html), the sort of thing you're after is the right image correct?

Comment: Can this be set up to overlay an entire div of contents?

Comment: @kyllle Yeah just whatever div you set the function to make sure you have that on position:relative

Answer (score 1):

Just the basics to get the idea:

```
<div id="content">This is the hovered content.</div>
<div id="readmore" style="display:none;">Read more...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#content').mouseover(function(){
        $('readmore').show();
    });
    $('#content').mouseover(function(){
        $('readmore').hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

Do browse through jQuery website for good examples on documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the jQuery qTip plug-in.  You can do what you want with some nice cross-browser style.

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/